# Rails 3 Including Nested Module Inside Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller that I'd like to include some standard methods.

```
class Main::UsersController < Main::BaseController
  include MyModule::ControllerMethods
end
```

`uninitialized constanct MyModule::ClassMethods::InstanceMethods`

My module looks like this, which is also wrong, and was originally meant for a model. What's the best way to do it so that I can use it with a controller as well?

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.has_one  :example, :autosave => true
    base.before_create :make_awesome        

    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    ...
    include InstanceMethods
  end

  module InstanceMethods
     ...
  end

  module ControllerMethods
    ...
    # I want to include these in my controller
    def hello; end
    def world; end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `extend` instead of `include` for your ClassMethods. You should also split your model and controller modules:

```
module MyModule    
  module ModelMethods
    def acts_as_something
      send :has_one,  :example, :autosave => true
      send :before_create, :make_awesome  
      send :include, InstanceMethods
    end
    module InstanceMethods
      ...
    end


  end

  module ControllerMethods
    ...
    # I want to include these in my controller
    def hello; end
    def world; end
  end

end

ActiveRecord::Base.extend MyModule::ModelMethods
```

Your Model would then look like this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_something
end
```

Comment: This article by Yehuda Katz goes in to more detail about why just using extend is better than overriding include to extend: http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/

Comment: Just curious, you put `Base.extend MyModule::ModelMethods`, but what does `Base` pertain to. Should it be `ActiveRecord::Base`?

Comment: I thought I would keep it simple by using `Base`, but it's probably more confusing. I've changed the answer to use `ActiveRecord::Base`